# Simultaenously copy text from user input to text area

Tags: javascript, php

Hi I'm trying to have a system whereby a user can type their name, address, postcode etc. and the system generates a prewritten letter. All my code is currently in a PHP file.

```
<h2>Send your MP our pre-written letter</h2>
<p>Please fill out the information required below:</p>
<div align="left">
<form action="form.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"
    <p>Name <font color="red">(required) </font> <input name="flname" required placeholder="Your Name"> </p>
    <p>Email <font color="red">(required) </font> <input name="emailfrom" type="email" required placeholder="Your Email">  </p>
    <p>Address <font color="red">(required) </font> <input name="address" required placeholder="Address"> </p>
        <p>City <font color="red">(required) </font> <input name="city" required placeholder="City"> </p>
        What is 2+2? <font color="red">(required) </font> <input name="human"required placeholder="Type Here">
        <p> <b> You can edit the text below as much or as little as you wish </b> </p>

<script>

 $("input[name=name]").on('keyup', function () {
        $('#name1').html($(this).val());
    });

    $("input[name=address]").on('keyup', function () {
        $('#add1').html($(this).val());
    });
    $("select[name=city]").on('change', function () {
        $('#city1').html($(this).find('option:selected').text());
    });

</script>

<textarea name="text" required placeholder="Your Message" style="margin: 5px; width: 391px; height: 230px;">
Dear <?php echo "$mptitle $mpsecondname"?>,

Please support us

Kind Regards,
<?php 
echo "<p id="name1"></p>"
echo "<p id="add1"></p>" , echo "<p id="city1"></p>"
echo "$senderpostcode"?>
?>

</textarea>

</div>
</div>
</form>
```

However, this Javascript solution doesn't seem to be working. I'd like the text to appear under the Kind Regards, line without the submit button being clicked, i.e. live, so whilst the user types his name/address/city these values will appear in the specified order in real time.

Thanks for your help.

**Update 2:** Hi, the solution below seems to only yield:

Form can be seen in action at hhassan.me/codetest to seem what I mean, using ST5 3JL as a demo postcode.

Image below as an aid (can't embed as I'm a new user):

[https://i.stack.imgur.com/6N48v.png

Answer (score 2):

Move your JS to the end of the page, so that you are not referencing elements that the DOM has not loaded.  Use the syntax below to put your JS code, and place it at the end of your page..

```
<?php 
echo "<p id='name1'></p>";
echo "<p id='add1'></p>";
echo "<p id='city1'></p>";
echo "$senderpostcode";
?>
```

---

```
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

        // put JS code here    

    });
    </script> 

    </body>      
</html>
```

Comment: Hi, I'm getting a PHP error code: [Sun Jul 19 22:40:43.485178 2015] [:error] [pid 1706] [client 127.0.0.1:49412] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'name1' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ';' in /var/www/html/mplookup.php on line 96

Comment: You have syntax errors.. see my updated answer above

Comment: Thanks, but it outputs in the textarea as follows: 
<p id=''></p><p id=''></p><p id=''></p>B14 7QJ

Comment: OK, the issue is with your use of double/single quotes.  amended again.

Comment: Hi, it seems to be outputing <p id='name1'></p><p id='add1'></p><p id='city1'></p>

Comment: That is correct.  Now its just the JS that is not targetting those named elements and filling in the text - probably becaise they dont exist in the DOM at the point that your JS is referencing them.  So.. ..move your JS to the end..

Comment: You can't use HTML code in a `<textarea>` element.  You will need to build your string outside the <textarea> using \n for new lines...

Comment: Hi, I need it to output in the textarea so that it is submitted to form.php which then mails it.

Comment: I might be able to implement it using php mail's HTML email function and then print the variables.